# Pdf viewer using StoryBoard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have a problem with navigationController. I'm trying to make a simple PDF app using UIPageViewController but I can't get it working.

I tried to use the project UIPageViewController-PDF (https://github.com/jackhumphries/UIPageViewController-PDF) with StoryBoards but when the PDF shown the navigationBar disappears.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make pdf-viewer controller, just use `UIWebView`.

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this PDF reader in my apps: https://github.com/vfr/Reader

It's pretty easy to setup programmatically (and should work fine with your Storyboard). You could also go ahead and customise is to your liking.